# Handling FileResult from JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC C# Controller that returns a FileResult

```
    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult FinaliseQuote(string quote)
    {
        var finalisedQuote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FinalisedQuote>(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(quote));

        return File(finalisedQuote.ConvertToPdf(), "application/pdf");
    }
```

Now I want to be able to download the result (I don't want it to open up in the browser) 
I am calling the controller via $.ajax method in JavaScript

```
var postData = { quote: finalisedQuote };

var url = "/NewQuote/FinaliseQuote";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: postData,
    success: function (data) {
        //how do I handle data to force download
    },
    fail: function (msg) {
        alert(msg)
    },
    datatype: "json"
});
```

How do I handle the data to force it to download?

Answer (score 10):

You won't be able to use JavaScript to save the file to disk as this is blocked for security reasons.

An alternative would be to save the file in the `FinaliseQuote` action method (and return just an id for the file), then create another action method that responds to a GET request and returns the file. In your success function you then set `window.location.href` to point to your new action method (you'll need to pass an id for the file). Also make sure you set the MIME type to `application/octet-stream` and that should force the browser to download the file.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FinaliseQuote(string quote)
{
    var finalisedQuote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FinalisedQuote>(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(quote));

    // save the file and return an id...
}

public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/file{0}.pdf", id)));

    // this is needed for IE to save the file instead of opening it
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename\""); 

    return File(fs, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

**JS:**

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = "/NewQuote/DownloadFile?id=" + data;
},
```

Comment: Yes this was my plan b. Ok I'll go with that. It just seems like double handling

Comment: You could move things around a bit and pass all the data needed to create the file directly to the DownloadFile action, that way you wouldn't need to do the ajax request